# "Permission denied" error when changing the default applications

Tags: 11.10, default-programs

I'm trying to change the default applications in Ubuntu 11.10 and I fail to do so.

I go to system info > default applications and I make some changes. If I close and reopen the system info window, the changes have reverted to the old ones.

Also if I go to a .avi for example > properties > open with and I try to set as default something else, I get

> **Could not set as default**
>
> Error while setting "VLC media player" as default application: Failed
>   to create file
>   '/home/george/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list.WCOC3V':
>   Permission denied

Comment: I have not tested this because I do not want to mess with my system, but are you logged-in as a standard user? Does your user have administration privileges?

Comment: Yes I'm logged in as a standard user. Why should I need administration privileges to change the default application for something for my user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Not sure if it's the best one.

The ***/home/george/.local/share/applications*** directory was owned by root. Not sure if it was meant to be that way. Anyway after I changed owner, I can now set some other program as the default without problem.

```
sudo chown -R george:george /home/george/.local/share/applications
```

As an addition, now the changes from ***system info*** work as well